# Convert AA to MP3

Tags: itunes, music, file-conversion

I bought an audio book from audible and want to convert it to mp3 from aa because my phone doesn't support the format. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org).

From their [manual](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Audible-AAX):

> Audible AAX files are encrypted M4B files, and they can be decrypted
>   by specifying a 4 byte activation secret.

```
ffmpeg -activation_bytes 1CEB00DA -i input.aax -vn -c:a copy output.mp3
```

Since the file is encrypted, you will need the activation secret in order to decrypt and convert.

Comment: Use https://audible-converter.ml/ to get the "activation bytes" from an Audible aax file.

Comment: The manual states "output.mp4", not "output.mp3", as written above. Changing the output to mp3 gives an error and creates an empty file. The answer is to create an mp4 file and then convert that to an mp3 file. There may be a more elegant way, but I can attest that this two-step approach works. See superuser.com/q/332347/1340043 for mp4 to mp3 conversion